# Difference between rpm -ivh and rpm -Uvh

Tags: linux, rpm

Hi i am newbie in linux can anyone explains me the difference between

> rpm -ivh

and

> rpm -Uvh

Comment: Did you try to read the `man` ?

Comment: @Thomas could you guide me towards any reading link that would be really helpful...

Comment: when in linux you should type: `man rpm`. The same goes for most linux programs... (eg `man find`)

Comment: @ChrisMaes or even `man man`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Check out [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/8/rpm) (man page) of rpm.

> i - install (This installs a new package)
>   v - verbose (using or expressed in more words than are needed)
>   h - hash (Print 50 hash marks as the package archive is unpacked)
>   U - upgrade (This upgrades or installs the package currently installed to a newer version. This is the same as install, except all other version(s) of the package are removed after the new package is installed)

Comment: It should be capital ``U``.